# How to use one rig for 2 objects

Tags: rigging

I am currently working on 2 low poly characters and want to have them rigged, so I can pose them. I already made the first body, applied a rig and edited the weight paint. Now I want to copy the body with the applied rig for the second character. Is there a way to copy everything and apply a second pose?

Comment: If you want to transfer the weight from the first object to the second you can use the Data Transfer modifier. But what do you mean by "apply a second pose"?

Comment: My scene consists of 2 character, which have the same body. I was wondering if i could just duplicate the body and  metarig, but be able to pose the rig from the second character apart from the first.

Comment: yes, just duplicate the mesh and its armature, if you want another action for the new armature, close the current one in the Dope Sheet (switch the Dope Sheet to Action Editor mode), and create a new one, so that this second armature doesn't share the same action